# http post through varnish to weblogic takes ~30 sec for 302 redirect

Tags: varnish, weblogic12c, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have a J2EE application running on following deployment architecture

F5 LB --> Varnish 4 on RHEL 7 --> APACHE 2.4 on RHEL7 --> WebLogic 12.1.2.1 http proxy plug-in --> WebLogic 12.1.2.1

**Case:** In all such cases where user does a form submit (http post) and after performing some action (say database save) application server does 302 redirects to a new page (success page). Weblogic adds a lag of approx 30 sec before redirecting to success page.

**Genesis of problem:** This problem we have started facing recently when we did platforms upgrade.

**Pls note following**

**Old setup** - radware LB +  varnish 3.0.6 on RHEL6 + Apache 2.2 + weblogic 10.3.6(11g)(above mentioned use case works fine)

**New setup** - F5 LB + (RHEL 7 + apache 2.4 + weblogic 12.1.2.1) with following versions of varnish

**No varnish -** works fine

**Varnish 3.0.6 -** weblogic adds 30 sec delay

**Varnish 4/5 -** works fine on firefox, weblogic adds 30 sec delay on IE 11

Comment: It appears this should be a bug report to Varnish rather than a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks! Our tech stack is pretty standard one(as I shared above). I doubt that it might be unnoticed bug in all varnish versions! I hope I get some help from varnish or weblogic experts!